# Rewrite subdomain to main domain without redirect with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

Hello I want to rewrite sub.domain.com to domain.com/sub.
But also sub2.domain.com needs to be rewritten to domain.com/sub2 and sub3 etc...
The url is not allowed to change so a redirect is not an option.
My current code is an endless redirect:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://sub.domain.com/$1 [L]
```

How can I change the .htaccess to get this fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop happens because you rewrite to `sub.domain.com` which then triggers the cond because of the presence of `sub.` and rewrites again.

If you don't want the address to change, you can try using the proxy flag instead. Make sure `mod_proxy` is enabled:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://domain.com/%1/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Thank you verry much. I now why the loop happens but I didn't know how to solve it without redirecting. The proxy flag did it :)