# change the subdomain without creating subdomain using htaccess url Rewriting php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

I have a website http://www.example-domain.com and I want to rewrite the URL so that I can change this subdomain with the subdomain I want, like I want this URL to be called like http://abc.example-domain.com instead of http://www.example-domain.com and still get the same page being loaded as we are getting on http://www.example-domain.com, i dont want a new subdomain with name 'abc' instead i want my url to be rewritten in  such a way that it looks like that it's a subdomain in it but actually it isn't and i need it to be done by using URL REWRITING using htaccess.
plz elaborate a bit along with you solution.
thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rewrite subdomain to main domain without redirect with htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33217233/rewrite-subdomain-to-main-domain-without-redirect-with-htaccess)

Comment: No, that post is changing the place of the subdomain and I don't want that, instead I just want to have an impact of the rewriting on the subdomain content and not the position of the subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

The browser will look up the IP address of the subdomain in the DNS (Domain Name System) find nothing and load an error page.

Comment: well I can change  http://www.example-domain.com/index.php by rewriting url, isn't it possible for sudomain part as well ???

Comment: If the subdomain points to your server too, maybe. But from your question I thought it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup wildcard subdomain.

Check this, if it helps for you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/758383/11426374